# Confluent cp-kafka-connect Docker image Health is starting state

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have been following this guide https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html to run kafka through docker. 
However, the connect is not working at all. It is always saying me as :

`connect           /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up (health: starting)`

Can anyone has a solution of the same?

[image]

Comment: did you finish with the configuration ? and what is in docker logs ?

Comment: Do you have enough memory configured in Docker to start all those containers?

Comment: @cricket_007 Spot on! It has worked. However, I am getting an another error with  ksql-datagen      bash -c echo Waiting for K .

Comment: @codebased Can you update your question with this new part re. ksql-datagen? Full logs please.

Comment: @codebased I am also getting same  Up (health: starting) please answer here how you solved it

Comment: @Mahantesh Yes, by increasing my memory in docker settings has helped.

Comment: @codebased Thanks, I also did the same, which is solved mine also.